# Ajax edit page in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this page Index page:

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Who</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.description %></td>
    <td><%= user.who %></td>
    <%= render 'users/form' %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

Scaffold controller

```
def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end
```

I need to edit user in index page, not to go url /users/2/edit, stay on users page.

How I do this in Ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `remote:true` to the `Edit` line in order to make an ajax call:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user), remote:true %></td>
```

Also, add an `edit.js.erb` file (a javascript file with embedded ruby) in which you do all the javascript actions to be executed after the `Edit`. That `edit.js.erb` file is generated when the `edit` method is done. This is where you write all the changes to the javascript code which affect the current page (the page will not be re-rendered).

Additionally, add the following to the `edit` method:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.js
end
```